# How to include imported fields in the search results?

Tags: vespa

I'm using [document references](http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/search-definitions.html#document-references) to import parent fields into a child document. While searches against the parent fields work, the parent fields themselves do not seem to be included in the search results, only child fields.

To use the example in the documentation, `salesperson_name` does *not* appear in the `fields` entry for `id:test:ad::1` when using `query=John`, or indeed when retrieving `id:test:ad::1` via `GET` directly.

Here's a simplified configuration for my document model:

## search definitions

### person.sd - the parent

```
search person {
  document person {
    field name type string {
      indexing: summary | attribute
    }
  }

  fieldset default {
    fields: name
  }
}
```

### event.sd - the child

```
search event {
  document event {
    field code type string {
      indexing: summary | attribute
    }
    field speaker type reference<person> {
      indexing: summary | attribute
    }
  }

  import field speaker.name as name {}

  fieldset default {
    fields: code
  }
}
```

## documents

### p1 - person

```
{
  "fields": {
    "name": "p1"
  }
}
```

### e1 - event

```
{
  "fields": {
    "code": "e1",
    "speaker": "id:n1:person::1"
  }
}
```

### query result

`curl -s "http://localhost:8080/search/?yql=select%20*%20from%20sources%20*where%20name%20contains%20%22p1%22%3B" | python -m json.tool`

This returns both e1 and p1, as you would expect, given that `name` is present in both. *But* the `fields` of `e1` do not include the `name`.

```
{
  "root": {
    "children": [
      {
        "fields": {
          "documentid": "id:n1:person::1",
          "name": "p1",
          "sddocname": "person"
        },
        "id": "id:n1:person::1",
        "relevance": 0.0017429193899782135,
        "source": "music"
      },
      {
        "fields": {
          "code": "e1",
          "documentid": "id:n1:event::1",
          "sddocname": "event",
          "speaker": "id:n1:person::1"
        },
        "id": "id:n1:event::1",
        "relevance": 0.0017429193899782135,
        "source": "music"
      }
    ],
    ...
    "fields": {
      "totalCount": 2
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Currently you'll need to add the imported 'name' into the default summary by

```
 import field speaker.name as name {}

 document-summary default {
    summary name type string{}
  }
```

More about explicit document summaries in http://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/document-summaries.html

The result of your query will then return

```
 "children": [
        {
            "fields": {
                "documentid": "id:n1:person::1",
                "name": "p1",
                "sddocname": "person"
            },
            "id": "id:n1:person::1",
            "relevance": 0.0017429193899782135,
            "source": "stuff"
        },
        {
            "fields": {
                "code": "e1",
                "documentid": "id:n1:event::1",
                "name": "p1",
                "sddocname": "event",
                "speaker": "id:n1:person::1"
            },
            "id": "id:n1:event::1",
            "relevance": 0.0017429193899782135,
            "source": "stuff"
        }
    ],
```

We'll improve the documentation on this. Thanks for the very detailed write-up.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! One ask for the docs (which are very very good from a standing start), could you include more examples of the output result JSON, as above. This is almost a "missing link" in some places. Otherwise, you tend to need to put together a test case to see what will actually be produced! :)

Answer (score 2):

Add "summary" to the indexing statement of the imported field in the parent document type.

E.g in the documentation example change the "name" field in the "salesperson" document type to say "indexing: attribute | summary".

Comment: Nope doesn't work :) This is on the latest version as of today: https://hub.docker.com/r/vespaengine/vespa/tags/ 6.176.233